# Migrating ActiveStorage assets from one S3 bucket to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am trying to migrate a large number of ActiveStorage images from an old S3 bucket to a new one.  I'm not quite sure why, but it seems all of the checksums are invalid because none of the migrated assets work (I also upgraded from Rails 5.2 to 6.1 and ran the variant migrations for ActiveStorage).

I get `URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?): nil)` and it falls back to local storage despite everything being set up correctly.  It generates a localhost link to a 404.

`Disk Storage (36.0ms) Generated URL for file at key: yyTi9oJYzd7rTqEQeE12qnXX ()`

Whereas if I upload a brand new asset it works just fine and creates a valid link to S3 so I know S3 is set up correctly.

```
S3 Storage (14.9ms) Generated URL for file at key: q38vgec9kpzl6ibl5baq3cgdzvuz (https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/long-check-sum-which-works-fine-here.....)
```

With a working S3 link to an image that exists!

I'm assuming this is a checksum issue as the keys are there and have matching files on S3 (and it works for new images).  Is there a way I can regenerate all of the checksums?  Unless someone has another idea for why these are not able to be generated properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Rails 6.1 stores the name of the storage service with the ActiveStorage blob. Maybe this is causing an issue here? Have you renamed the service? I have moved from one bucket to another by simply copying the files and updating the service credentials without issue.

Comment: You are beautiful, that worked perfectly, I feel silly I missed that in the migration and hadn't yet set up S3 before I had run it.  Thanks for that.